# How to make a dataset reactive in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr

I would like to use a reactive dataset in my shiny app, such that any other objects that uses that dataset can be re-rendered according to the values in `reactiveDf`.

In this example I am outputting only one table, but in my app I have other charts and tables, and the idea is to trigger the rendering by subsetting `reactiveDf` only. Also, I would like to do that using `dplyr`.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        checkboxGroupInput('Category', '',
                           unique(mtcars$carb), selected = unique(mtcars$carb))),
      # Show table of the rendered dataset
      mainPanel(
         tableOutput("df")
      )
   )
))


server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  reactiveDf <- reactive({tbl_df(mtcars) %>% 
                                  filter(carb %in% input$Category)})

   output$df <- renderTable({reactiveDf})
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Right now, when I run this app I get:

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:7032
Warning: Error in UseMethod: no applicable method for 'xtable' 
applied to an object of class "reactive"
```

And `tableOutput()` is not displayed.

Comment: @cory If I do `str(tbl_df(mtcars))` I get `Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame`. Do you mean that the object should be _exclusively_ a dataframe? 
I am using ggvis too in my original app, and that's way I was trying to stick with dplyr for the subsetting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A reactive is a function... so you need parens...

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxGroupInput('Category', '',
                         unique(mtcars$carb), selected = unique(mtcars$carb))),
    # Show table of the rendered dataset
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("df")
    )
  )
))


server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  reactiveDf <- reactive({return(tbl_df(mtcars) %>% 
      filter(carb %in% input$Category))})

  output$df <- renderTable({reactiveDf()})
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks, my brutal copy/pasting from here and there didn't make me realize that I was actually defining a function and assigning it to `reactiveDf`.

Comment: It's definitely not intuitive, don't feel bad.