# How to embed a value from a reactive dataset in a tags() function in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, mustache

In the shiny app below, I would like to print out parts of the two reactive datasets (`reactiveDf` and `reactive2`) using the function `tags` but the script I have is not working.

I know I could use other solutions like renderTable, but later on I need to embed this reactive code in a html page using `{{}}`, thus it would be wonderful if somebody can explain to me why this is not working.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxGroupInput('Category', '',
                         unique(mtcars$carb), selected = unique(mtcars$carb))),
    # Show table of the rendered dataset
    mainPanel(
      tags$div(reactiveDf()),
      tags$div(reactive2())
    )
  )
))


server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  reactiveDf <- reactive({return(tbl_df(mtcars) %>% 
                                   filter(carb %in% input$Category))})
  reactive2 <-  reactive({reactiveDf()[1,]})
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Are you using `{{ mustache }}`? Just in case you didn't know, they have an [`R` package](https://github.com/edwindj/whisker) which may help out later in the process when you need to pass it to JS.

Comment: I am using a custom template (`htmlTemplate()`), and I am embedding part of code with `{{}}` which I didn't know it was actually an implementation of the `{{mustache}}` standard. Generally, I am referring to [this page](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/templates.html).
I am not sure if want to use `whisker` right now, unless you strongly recommend it as a best practice every time we write shiny apps linked to html code. But thanks for your suggestion as I might need it in the future.

Comment: I was more curious than anything; I can't vouch for `whiskers` myself, had a friend who used it. Just saw the syntax and wondered what you were doing with it. I messed around it with it for a while but couldn't figure it out either, sorry, I hope someone comes along who can help!

Comment: you can't use `reactiveDF()` like that in the `ui`

Comment: what do you mean by " embed this reactive code in a html page" - shiny **is** an html page? (also, I'm not familiar with `mustache {{}}`, so may be missing something)

Comment: @Symbolix In my original app I am using a custom template with `htmlTemplate()` as shown [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/templates.html). However, right now the question is limited to what I have posted, i.e. printing part of a dataset in an html tag. Could you comment on why reactiveDf() cannot be used like that?

Comment: In [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36203640/5977215) you can wrap your `tableOutput` in a `tags$div()`:   `tags$div(tableOutput("df"))`.

Comment: An as for how to use a reactive function in the `ui`, I can't do any better than point you to the [shiny documentation](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/)

Comment: @Symbolix I wanted to embed the output in a `tags()` because in my original app, I need to put in my html page some values from `reactiveDf`. In fact, I would like to do something like `{{reactiveDf()[1,1]}}`, which doesn't work. Thus, I was trying to reach this result step-by-step by first printing the desired output in a `tags$x()` function.

Comment: does `tags$div(tableOutput("df"))` not work for you? All your reactive work has to be done on the `server`. You then return this to the `ui`. You can also render the ui/html elements in the server and send back with `renderUI`.

Comment: I followed what you suggested, combined with a careful reading of the documentation, and I did the job. Thanks.

Comment: No problem; glad it worked :)  you should add it as an answer to your own question